# Most efficient way to combine video and audio in real time with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to capture and combine webcam video and (separate) USB microphone audio on a not-super-fast machine (Raspberry Pi 4B).  If I capture separately, everything goes smoothly and I use only a fraction of available CPU.  But when I try to combine the two input streams into one file, I get many "Non-monotonous DTS" and "ALSA buffer xrun" warnings, and the output audio drops after a few seconds.

**What's an efficient ffmpeg invocation to do this?**

Here's one of many commands I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f alsa -i default:CARD=Elf -f v4l2 -framerate 4 -i /dev/video0 -r 4 t26.avi
```

I'm an experienced programmer but new to ffmpeg, so perhaps I'm making some obvious blunders.

I'm aiming for 4 frames per second to save space and (hopefully) also reduce CPU load.  I want to keep the audio quality high, though.

Perhaps combining the two input streams forces some format conversions/reencoding, and perhaps some intermediate steps are at a high frame rate?  If so, is there a way to combine video and audio streams that avoids this?

Comment: Show the complete console output from your command (without `-hide_banner`).